# Как обновить переменную среды PATH при выполнении bat файла в cmd windows?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, bat

Стоит задача установить программу и несколько модулей. Я хочу сделать это через bat файл примерно такого вида

```
python-3.6.4.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1
pip install intelhex-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
pip install pyserial-3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Проблема в том, что после установки python переменная среды для запущенной cmd.exe не обновляется, поэтому она не находит программу pip, которая устанавливается вместе с python.

Подскажите, как обновить переменную PATH при выполнении файла bat из cmd?

Comment: Да запщеная консоль остается со своим окружением, что обновилось надо открыть новую. Попробуйте разбить это файл на 2 батника. 1 установка питона, 2 с pip. Проверьте может быть можно вызвать 2 из 1.

Comment: @Kers пробовал, всё равно не подхватывает переменную. Работает только если отдельно их по очереди запускать, но так неудобно будет.

Comment: Как вариант если путь установки известен то можно запускать прописав путь к `pip.exe` например: `C:\Python\Scripts\ pip.exe install intelhex-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`. Пока конечно так мысли сам проверить смогу к сожалению только вечером.

Comment: @Kers, можно указать путь для установки, правда такое решение не очень универсаьное

Comment: С универсальным это обернуть в инсталлятор который потом выполнит скрипт (inno setup к примеру), или сделать собственную обвязку на другом(желательно компилируемом) языке.

Comment: Несколько [способов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856234/) решения задачи имеется на SO.

Answer (score 0):

только Vista+

```
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

python-3.6.4.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1

setx temp "%temp%"

pip install intelhex-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

pip install pyserial-3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```